# Entity Framework Conditional Count of Navigation Property 2 levels down

Tags: entity-framework, frameworks, count, entity

Just starting out with Entity Framework and am trying to work out how you would do something like this....

Say I have the following entities, Customers that have Orders that have OrderLineItems which are linked to Products. I would like to return the name of every customer with a count of the number of times they have ordered a particular product.

I have seen examples of using .Count() but these have always been for the first navigation property i.e. number of orders per customer.

Would appreciate some guidance here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work, where `context` is your `DbContext` instance.

It will return an `IEnumerable<dynamic>`, although obviously you could make a class to hold the results.

```
// The product to count
var productId = 12345;

context.Customers.Include("Orders.OrderLineItems.Products")
  .Select(customer => 
        new {
              CustomerName = customer.Name,
              ProductCount = customer.Orders
                .SelectMany(o => o.OrderLineItems)
                .SelectMany(i => i.Products.Where(p => p.Id = productId).Count()
            });
```

The `Include()` extension method is useful, it will make sure that the resulting SQL query joins the relevant tables together - otherwise multiple queries would be executed for each customer (one to get orders, another for line items and a final one for products).

Comment: Hi @greg84. I only seem to get the .SelectMany option for customer orders. I can't type customer.SelectMany() I have to go customer.Orders.SelectMany(). Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Yes sorry, I've updated the answer. That should work. `SelectMany` is an extension method that applies to collections, and `Customer` isn't a collection so it's not going to work. I've not tested the code above, but it should be about right.